# Attitude to judge and avoid efforts

Tags: discussion

I've [opened a question trying to point out every doubt I had on a language of development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655534/how-does-catcomplete-works): I thought it could be constructive.

**I'm pretty proud of the formulation of this question since it gives almost nothing as understood. While I was studying math at university many books were giving many concept as known.**

At the moment in which I'm writing 5 persons downvoted the question saying: "*How about learning something about 1) JavaScript objects ({}), 2) jQuery callbacks 3) jQuery plugins?*"

Actually there is a cognitive error in this sentence. He thinks (opinion) that I've lacked of effort, but actually I've studied Javascript at the university (fact). I've also tried to google for it (fact), but without the exact knowledge of what to look for I could not find an explanation. *I'm making an assumption interpreting his sentence.*

**Another guy simply answered in a constructive way.**

Comment: Maybe he wasn't judging, maybe he was actually giving you a legitimate answer (in a very concise form)

Comment: @StrangeLoop: for judging I mean: choosing an opinion, making up a belief based on considerations. We judge as we breathe.. I think we cannot avoid judging. The problem is that the beliefs we make up can be rational or not..

Comment: The person who answered your question doesn't seem like they hold irrational beliefs; it seems like they just wanted to give you tips on what to Google to find the answer. I think he was just too lazy to explain all the questions you asked, so he simply gave you some keywords to Google (in a comment instead of an answer) and figure it out for yourself. It's not as constructive as answering all the questions in a long, detailed, amazing answer, but it's definitely constructive.

Comment: @StrangeLoop: for me was useful in any case, and we cannot read his mind. But I got 5 dowvnote.. and he said: "How about learning something about..." which is different from saying: "look for...". However, I can be wrong for him, but what about the downvotes? Let's consider the hypothesy which explains the downvotes as motivated by this explanations or the one given by deviero here.

Comment: I think you may be reading too much into his wording, which can be interpreted to have a sarcastic tone. However, online, you shouldn't make up a belief based on no evidence, right? We don't know if he was being sarcastic. He gave reasonable tips on what to Google, IMO, so his comment is a positive contribution. I'm guessing the reason you got downvoted is independent of his comment - it's probably just because there's a lot to explain in your question that's better learnt on your own by Googling the topics. (Which is clearly possible, it's not like they are some esoteric subjects)

Comment: By the way, I don't think you should have gotten downvoted, but I do think it's hard to explain so much stuff in an answer. So I find it his answer acceptable - even the accepted answer is very brief and doesn't really explain much to someone who doesn't know about objects, callbacks, and plugins.

Comment: @StrangeLoop: yes, you are not wrong, but look also to this question which is really easier to google for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558754/define-what-is-a-hashset what do you say then? I could understand an answer like the comment of the user, but downvotes no..

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either. I don't think there's any cognitive errors/biases/self-esteem issues in play here though.

Comment: @StrangeLoop: but almost everything we do is motivated by our cognition.. To hit someone that we don't like we try to see him as bad or stupid before. Being proud is a very huge need for human.

Comment: Sure, I do agree in general. I just don't see how it's the case here.

Comment: @StrangeLoop: the user doensn't want to provide an explanation since it's boring for him. It would be constructive and if he would be coherent he should simply do it. He doesn't want to accept that he is more lazy and egoistic than he wants to admit to himself. So he has to focus a reason for not answering the question. This will let him distract from his defects to focus on other's. Almost everytime we blame someone we could choose to make an effort at his place (I could spend hours reading all the javascript manual for example). The nice of psychology is the lack of any etical judgement..

Comment: @StrangeLoop: for example.. people like to tell themself that they stay on this community to improve it. But they try to hide to themselves that they are doing it also to improve their self-esteem, that they do it in the working time, that they do it mostly because is a way to spend time, to get a self-esteem pumping and that they simply prefer to avoid some tasks and find a valid rational justification, focus on it and hide all the other also rational which say why he is lazy, wrong, unconstructive and so on

Comment: Why do you doubt that people here get pleasure out of improving the quality of this community?

Comment: Do you have a point or are you just ranting? Consider just learning your lesson and doing more research next time to ask a better question.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: I think the word ranting is offensive. This question has been denaturated and moved to a section for which is wrong, however I will not delete it. I'm learning lot of lessons. Do you learn lessons? Some time ago I adviced this community to warn people before question banning I got said that I should listen more than speaking and.. at the end the community changed according to my advice. Youur answers appear often superficial. Also the edit you made to my question showed that you didn't read it.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: many high rep users here always start from the idea they are right. Even if you bring them scientific evidences that they are using cognitive distortions no one admit his fault. "just ranting", "just learning your lesson" are sentence which are not neutral speaking but are arrogant.

Comment: Related: *[Can "doubt" sometimes mean "question"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question)*

Answer (score 7):

Note here I'm not addressing whether the question mentioned in this Meta question *should* have been downvoted. I'm only addressing this idea:

> Attitude to judge and avoid efforts

and this (which has been deleted in a revision of the question):

> Can it be motivated by the need for feeding self-esteem while putting no effort in making something constructive?

Here we go again with the idea that if someone downvotes, or comments about a problem in the question instead of *just answering* they are something 'avoid[ing] efforts" or "putting no effort in making something constructive".

I guess the mental picture of this putative slacker who wants to avoid effort must be something like this: "Hmm.... I could try to answer these questions which would take a lot of time... or I could just downvote them in 2 minutes and then play Candy Crush for an hour. Yeah.... I'll just downvote. Yippee!!"

I'd venture to say that for most of the SO regulars the stakes are not at all like this. I've said it before and I'm going to say it again. The calculation is not between helping putting a bad question into shape or *doing nothing* but between working on *this bad question* versus working on *other questions* (or performing other tasks that help the site) that may be of higher quality in the first place.

I think most of us who have posted hundreds of answers to the site have, at some point or another, posted an answer on a question that was not that great and found that the OP could not handle the answer or changed the question because another problem was uncovered, we edited, and the OP still did not get it, or changed the question *again*, rinse and repeat. It has certainly happened to me on a number of times, with the ultimate result that the OP had an answer that the OP could not use and the problem was not a problem that anybody else could benefit from looking at. **At the end of the day such exercise adds no value to the site. Effort was expended, in vain.**

So **to avoid dumping energy into a black hole**, we downvote, comment, vote to close, or flag or whatever rather than engage with questions that are likely to end up wasting our time. And once we've done that, we move on to a question that is of better quality. Maybe it needs a little nudge, or maybe it is already in shape to be answered.

Overall this is a sane approach. There's a subjective factor to this, for sure. It does not entail that the practice should be abandoned. And the fact that an answer is posted and that the OP is satisfied is not **in and of itself** evidence that the downvotes, critical comments, etc, are unwarranted. I've seen answers where basically the answerer managed guess correctly the issue in a very vague question. It does not mean that the question was not, in fact, too vague.

Comment: Wait, you put a lot of meat on the fire. I tried to explain my opinion in another place and I will try to just say something very synthetic also here. Threre are 12 downvotes!!!! Whatever had happened is emotional driven. For a rational being one downvote was enough. This is a very important point. Second point. You expressed a lot of belief. Let's take just one: "At the end of the day such exercise adds no value to the site".. This assumption is based on other 2-3 big assumption which is based on other 20. The first answer I would give you is that this sentence is simply OT in this case..

Comment: @Revious: None of us can downvote (or upvote) a post more than once. And would you also say a single upvote is enough? Everyone who expended effort reading a post is encouraged to vote as it deserves, specifically ignoring how others voted: Upvote if useful, clear and well-researched, downvote if not, and meh if ... simply meh. That's because the score should reflect the judgement of the community as a whole, it will be quite useless otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

The competence you have and the competence you need has a big gap to understand the code.

You said that

> He thinks (opinion) that I've lacked of effort, but actually I've
>   studied Javascript at the university (fact).

My assumption (might be wrong) is that you have taken one or two courses of JavaScript there. If you have studied JavaScript at the university, that does not prevent you to study more of it at your own to understand the basic code syntax better.

Overly exaggerated example of this case would be that someone asks at Physics forum:
"Could you explain me the theory of relativity in detail?"

...and the person has just taken one physics course in high school.

If many users ask that kind of questions, expect answers and get them on Stack Overflow, then it is full of similar questions and more experienced users have nothing else to do than to explain things in words of one syllable. In that case the forum would not work efficiently.

I did not answer to your questions, because I think that you are approaching this problem from a wrong angle.

Anyway, you are correct that users in Stack Overflow should behave more constructive way. People are more critical there to the formulation of the questions than in other Stack Exchange sites for some reason.

Comment: I almost completely agree on what you are saying (+1). But one guy answered in a very profitable way.. And my question was specific to a JQuery plugin. And the concept were not so basic. And the next time someone asks a similar question he can be redirected to my question (marked as dup). The real question is: "does the question and answer add an information gain? or in common terms, are they useful? are they teaching something which may be useful for many?". I would say that it can be useful just for a few... million people. But also I got downvotes instead of explanations.. and a last stuff

Comment: "If many users ask that kind of questions, expect answers and get them on Stackoverflow, then it is full of similar questions and more experienced users have nothing else to do than to explain things in words of one syllable. In that case the forum would not work efficiently." this belief that you give as objective has many assumptions. One very big is that: "If many users ask that kind of questions". When you want to be objective you have to split any belief and wonder: "why I think this will happen? am I sure?" and also "why I am sure it's bad?" and when you give an answer you should again

Comment: Examine your answer and wonder: "I think it's bad for this reason, but have I really considered everything? Forecasting the future is not easy. Economics show it pretty clear. Inflation is good or bad? It's really really and hard question and it depends a lot, you could write a book on it.."